# Hiding a text for Radio button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, struts2

Unable to hide a radio button option and text using Javascript

Below is the code that gets generated as part of the base page. My goal is to hide the 'Run Immediately' radio button where the text is 'Run Later'.

```
function initPage() {
      document.getElementsByName("runimmediately")[1].setAttribute("hidden",true);
    }
```

---

```
<body onload="initPage()">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Job Information</legend>
        <table summary='Job Information' width='90%' class='content-grid'>
            <tr>
    <td>Job Description</td>
    <td><input id='DESCRIPTION' name='description' maxlength='250' value='Input Details' size='50' onchange='isdescriptionValid(this)' type='text'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    <td><input name='runimmediately' type='radio' value='true'/>Run Immediately</td>
    <td><input checked='checked' value='false' name='runimmediately' type='radio'/>Run Later</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

and was able to not show the radio option but the text 'Run Later' still appears.

I also tried to hide the text and radio using XPath, but did not work.

Comment: I'm new at posting questions here. Please bear with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the parent td by giving it an id and adding display none to it:

```js
function initPage() {
      document.getElementById("later").style.display = "none";
      }
```

```html
<body onload="initPage()">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Job Information</legend>
     <table summary='Job Information' width='90%' class='content-grid'>
      <tr>
    <td>Job Description</td>
    <td><input id='DESCRIPTION' name='description' maxlength='250' value='Input Details' size='50' onchange='isdescriptionValid(this)' type='text'/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input name='runimmediately' type='radio' value='true'/>Run Immediately</td>
    <td id="later"><input checked='checked' value='false' name='runimmediately' type='radio'/>Run Later</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: By the way, use `<label for="idOfTheInput">Your label</label>` to associate a text to a control